# How to pass "exclusive" as parameter for rabbitmqadmin to declare a queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, command-line-interface

In Java there is option:

- queue - the name of the queue
- durable: true - if we are declaring a durable queue (the queue will survive a server restart)
- exclusive: true - if we are declaring an exclusive queue (restricted to this connection)
- autoDelete: true - if we are declaring an autodelete queue (server will delete it when no longer in use)
- arguments: other - properties (construction arguments) for the queue

`channel.queueDeclare(endPointName, true, false, false, null);`

for rabbitmqadmin, commandline How to pass parameter for exclusive=false using [rabbitmqadmin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) command line tool?

The documentation for [rabbitmqadmin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) tool doesnt have an example for this usecase.

I am looking for shell script command like this:

```
rabbitmqadmin declare queue name="endPointName" durable=true exclusive=false arguments={"x-message-ttl":86400000}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default if no `expires` argument set, `false` value used, so you have to pass it via `argument` json-formated argument. The shell command should looks like this:

```
$ rabbitmqadmin declare queue name=endPointName durable=true arguments='{"exclusive":false,"x-message-ttl":86400000}'
queue declared
```

Make sure you have valid json strnig, unless you'll get formatting issue. Also, wrap json string in single quotes or double quotes inside will be removed.

And then will see in management panel something like this:

[image]

Comment: can I query on commnadLine itself with some command to check output displayed in image for x-message-TTL and exclusive? `=ERROR REPORT==== 9-May-2014::22:49:24 ===
connection <0.345.0>, channel 1 - error:
{amqp_error,precondition_failed,
            "inequivalent arg 'x-message-ttl'for queue 'endPointName' in vhost '/': received the value '86400000' of type 'signedint' but current is none",
            'queue.declare'}`

Comment: Looks like you have already declared queue with the same name but with different arguments. In general, declare command is idempotent, but only if it called with exact parameters. To get declared queues list with full info you can run `rabbitmqadmin -f long -d 3 list queues` (example taken from http://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html)

Comment: command to check output displayed in image for x-message-TTL and exclusive? `rabbitmqadmin -f raw_json list queues`